# SonarQube coverage on multi-modules project

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage, sonarqube-scan

I have a multi-modules project in SonarQube. One of the modules did not have any unit-test so far. Now that I added a unit-test in this module, the overall coverage of the project decreased! Does it mean that when a module has no test, it is not included at all in the global coverage calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly deduced the situation: If there's no coverage at all, it's excluded from the calculations by default. On a language-by-language basis (available in Java) "force coverage to zero" functionality is available.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!